# Full width rmarkdown table with striped rows

Tags: r, r-markdown

I would like to create a pdf file with a table made of a data frame below. I would like that table to be striped. Moreover I would like to set the full_width parameter in kable to be true.

```
                  x         y
Min.    0.000855763  1.524041
1st Qu. 0.213202958  5.306872
Median  0.468276570  7.796895
Mean    0.485573837  7.860995
3rd Qu. 0.755634791 10.581267
Max.    0.991640189 13.732120
sd      0.294182193  3.050645
```

That code works perfectly

```
df %>% 
  kable(caption='Some caption', booktabs=T) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options=c('striped', 'hold_position'))
```

However after setting the full_width parameter to "T" the stripes disappear. Is there a method to create both striped and full width table?

That's my RMarkdown settings

```
---
title: "RMarkdown file"
author: Me
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{graphicx}
output: pdf_document
---
```

And I use the following libraries

```
library(ggplot2)
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)
```

The chunk options is set to

```
{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results='asis'}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with Latex, so I just tried to get it to work to see if I can help you try and find a solution. I had to make my own dataset, and I made it `html_document` output, but then you can just print to PDF from the browser to get your PDF output file.

Can you use `CSS` in latex? because what worked for me was adding the below CSS to stripe the kable table.

```
.table tr:nth-child(even) { background: #eee; }
```

````
---
title: "RMarkdown file"
author: Me
output: html_document
---

```
{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
```

```{css}
.table tr:nth-child(even) { background: #eee; }
```

```{r}
library(ggplot2)
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)

```



```{r}
x <- 1:10
y  <- 11:20

df <- data.frame(x,y)

df %>% 
  kable(caption='Some caption', booktabs=TRUE) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options=c('striped', 'hold_position'), full_width = TRUE)
```
````

Which gave me the table below[image]

Comment: actually after trying to print it to PDF, the PDF doesn't hold the striped rows.